# Reading a Block Structured ASCII file using Dask

Tags: dask

I have a ASCII file structured in blocks as follows (simplified version):

```
DATASET
OBJTYPE "mesh2d"
BEGSCL
ND 4
NC 10
NAME "Depth"
TIMEUNITS SECONDS
TS 0  0.00
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
TS 0  180.00
1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1
TS 0  360.00
1.2 2.2 3.2 4.2
TS 0  540.00
1.3 2.3 3.3 4.3
```

We can ignore the header lines and each block is started by the TS line that defines the timestep and is followed by a block of data 'ND' values long. The index of each data point in the block is just the location of the value in the block. The data blocks are delimited by the 'TS' lines.

I would like to read this in with Dask so I can process very large files. I think I need to use dask.read_bytes but in this case my delimiter is variable (i.e. 'TS 0 *\n') plus I need the timestep value for each block (i.e. the 180 in TS 0 180.00)

Some pointers on whether this is possible and how to proceed would be appreciated. The target file is approx 12GB.

Comment: You will probably need to read the header separately, use delimited `\nTS 0` and, for each block, get the timestep variable from the first line. You will needs your own custom function for processing each block.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be splitting on `\nTS` or `\nTS 0` read_bytes is only returning a single partition with the entire file.

Comment: Maybe just make a hdf5 file that contains an array with just numbers and no column/row names (with a parser you make and h5py library). And create a Dask array from the hdf5 file. If you read the file block by block, you might run into problem with delayed, lock, and writing.

Answer (score 0):

For the data sample given, you can do something like the following:

```
head, parts = dask.bytes.read_bytes(infile, delimiter=b'\nTS 0', blocksize=30)
```

Here, the `head` contains the leading bytes of the file (for this small case, the whole file! in general `sample=` controls this). Finding global metadata would probably be best achieved with regular expressions, if you don't already have code for this.

```
re.search(b'ND (\d+)', head).groups()[0]
b'4'
```

For the data, you will want a function something like the following. I am assuming dataframe output here. Also, I am guessing one line of data after each TS line, since that is what the sample has. This function may not be elegant or efficient, but it will get the job done

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask

@dask.delayed
def proc(bytes, meta):
    if len(bytes) == 0:
        return meta
    parts = bytes.split(b'\nTS 0')
    out = []
    for part in parts:
        if len(part) == 0:
            continue
        lines = part.split(b'\n')
        timestep = float(lines[0].strip())
        values = np.fromstring(lines[1], dtype=float, sep=' ')
        out.append(pd.DataFrame({'timestep': timestep, 'values': values}))
    return pd.concat(out)


meta = pd.DataFrame([], dtype=float, columns=['timestep', 'values'])
dd.from_delayed([proc(p, meta) for p in parts[0][1:]], meta=meta)
```

Notes:

- we provide a `meta`, because some blocks may be empty (as for the small blocksize in this example). We also skip the empty chunk at the end of each bytes block.
- the first block contains the header and should not be parsed as data (this is the `[1:]` selection). If it also contains data, extra code would need to deal with that (perhaps just try/except the parsing block)
- `parts` is a list of lists of delayed bytes; in theory there could have been multiple input files in the one call. How to handle them would depend on whether each has a header, and whether that information needs to be independently parsed from each file. Alternatively, dataframes as produced here could be concatenated.

Compute this code, I get

```
   timestep  values
0       0.0     1.0
1       0.0     2.0
2       0.0     3.0
3       0.0     4.0
0     180.0     1.1
1     180.0     2.1
2     180.0     3.1
3     180.0     4.1
0     360.0     1.2
1     360.0     2.2
2     360.0     3.2
3     360.0     4.2
0     540.0     1.3
1     540.0     2.3
2     540.0     3.3
3     540.0     4.3
```